# Unix: check the encoding of a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have got a file with special characters. And to load these files in hadoop hive the file should be in UTF-8.

When I type `file -bi $filename` command to get the encoding type, it gives me `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

I then used icon to convert to utf-8 by:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 $filename > ${filename}_conv
```

Now this utf-8 file is successfully loading into hive.
But when I run the `file -bi $${filename}_conv` command it gives:
`text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

I was expecting the charset to be utf8 but it is returning ascii.

Is there any other way to find the encoding. Because I may re-use the file and do not want to encode again.

There is no isutf8 or chardet and I tried file --mime.
All these doen't seem to work.

Is there any other command that can be used to determine the encoding type, would be really helpfull.

Thank you.

Comment: `us-ascii` simply means "file has no Unicode BOM, and no special char was found in the **sample** therefore it's probably an ASCII-7bit encoding"

Comment: You could use good old `tr` to remove all alphanum chars, and maybe all punctuation, to see what remains.

Comment: If I don't convert to utf-8 the output appears like O�LE instead of O´LE.

Comment: I used ISO8859-1 since the others iconv failed or created the incomplete file.

Comment: Help for _**what**_? You state that `iconv` produced a file converted to UTF-8 that gives a correct display in Hive. Fine. So the non-ASCII chars occur too far away from the top-of-file for `file` to detect them -- if you are not happy, develop your own utility.

Comment: You already converted the file, so you know its encoding. If you desperately need `file` to confirm this, pass it a fragment of the file which actually exhibits non-ASCII characters, like `grep -m1 -A 4 '[^ -~]' file.txt | file -` But anyway, this seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)